# Spectrum of two operators

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H=\big(L^2(\Bbb{R}^2),||.||\big)$, assumed to be unbounded. We have the following characterization of its spectrum $\sigma(A)$:

1. $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$ if and only if $\exists (u_n)\in D(A), \|u_n\|=1,$ such that $\lim_n \|(A-\lambda)u_n\|=0;$
2. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with infinite multiplicity if and only if there exists a sequence of linearly independent vectors $u_i\in D(A)$ such that $(A-\lambda)u_i=0;$
   of course $2$ is the form of $1$.
   Now we give another characterization of the essential spectrum of $A,$ denoted $\sigma_{ess}.$
3. $\lambda\in\sigma_{ess}(A)$ if and only if $\exists (u_n)\in D(A), \|u_n\|=1,$ $u_n\to 0$ weakly, such that $\lim_n \|(A-\lambda)u_n\|=0.$

I have self-adjoint operators $T=-\Delta_{\Bbb{R}^2}-(x^2+y^2)$ and $R=i(x\partial_y-y\partial_x)$ such that

(1) $\:\sigma(T)=\sigma_{ess}(T)=\Bbb{R}$ and the point spectrum of $T$ is empty; i.e., $\sigma_p(T)=\emptyset.$

(2) $\:\sigma(R)=\sigma_{ess}(R)=\sigma_p(R)=\Bbb{Z}$ (here any eigenvalue of $R$ has infinite multiplicity.)

(3)Note that $RT=TR$.

> **My question:** Let $a\in \sigma(T)=\sigma_{ess}(T)=\Bbb{R}$ and $m\in \sigma(R)=\sigma_{ess}(R)=\sigma_p(R)=\Bbb{Z}.$   Can I find a
>   sequence  $(u_n)\in D(R)\cap D(T),\quad\|u_n\|=1,\quad u_n\to 0$
>   weakly, such that $\lim_n \|(T-a)u_n\|=\lim_n
>  \|(R-m)u_n\|=0?$. I think there is no such sequence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your wording in your question does not parse in English. I'm talking about the wording "Can I have by $3$ of my assumptions ..." Did you mean, "Can I prove the three characterizations?"?

Comment: My question Can I find a sequence $(u_n)\in D(R)\cap D(T),\quad\|u_n\|=1,\quad u_n\to 0$ weakly, such that $\lim_n \|(T-\lambda)u_n\|=\lim_n \|(R-\lambda)u_n\|=0\,$?

Comment: Thanks, much better! Please take a close look at how I've formatted your question, so your future questions will get more attention.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you mean for your $\lambda$s in the "My question" block to be $a$ and $m$ respectively? Otherwise you aren't using $a$ and $m$ at all.

Comment: @or1426 . See above I made a correction.

Comment: I think there is no such sequence because: if $m\in\sigma_{ess}(R)$ implies $\exists (U_n)$  a sequence of linearly independent vectors such that $(R-m)U_n=0$ and no one of $U_n$ verify $(T-a)U_n=0$.

Comment: No one can respond me.